# How to launch a new program without pulling up the taskbar?

Tags: c#

I have an application ,running full screen, top most, and i want it so that when a user clicks a button it launches another exe file (also topmost) i can make it launch the EXE file with a new process, but the taskbar pops up whenever i do. How do i prevent the taskbar from comming up?

Comment: Wow!! I would hate to use your s/w :-) Why do you block users from seeing the Taskbar?

Comment: Likely building software for a kiosk or for full screen media playback (think XBMC).

Comment: @Sean in that case there is no need to load Windows Desktop/Taskbar or explorer.exe

Comment: @Shoban It would be if it was for an app like XBMC and they were trying to load a silverlight player to play Netflix or something.

Comment: @Shoban Why do any of us do the things we do? Because we need / are told too to solve a bigger problem

Comment: @Sean, @PostMan sorry guys.. I was just telling my personal opinion :-)

Comment: @Shoban Oh I was just saying :) Didn't mean to be rude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a different approach?

[This page](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29767194/windows-xp-taskbar-settings-via-registrygpo.aspx) has some registry key values to change task Bar settings. Why not disable "Always on Top" through your code. I must admit hiding/disabling the taskbar is very annoying from an user perspective.